# Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8. Error: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8: undefined symbol:

Tags: pytorch

I have docker image of pytorch2.0. I updated the torch version to 2.1.1, and ran the model. Now I am facing the below error.

```
Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8. Error: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8: undefined symbol: _ZN5cudnn3cnn5infer22queryClusterPropertiesERPhS3_, version libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8\
```

Is it possible to run the same or is there any dependency I am missing to upgrade?

This is traceback

```
  File "/home/tulsishah_google_com/dino/main_dino.py", line 471, in <module>
    train_dino(args)
  File "/home/tulsishah_google_com/dino/main_dino.py", line 273, in train_dino
    train_stats = train_one_epoch(student, teacher, teacher_without_ddp, dino_loss,
  File "/home/tulsishah_google_com/dino/main_dino.py", line 330, in train_one_epoch
    loss.backward()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 492, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 251, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: FIND was unable to find an engine to execute this computation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tulsishah_google_com/dino/main_dino.py", line 471, in <module>
    train_dino(args)
  File "/home/tulsishah_google_com/dino/main_dino.py", line 273, in train_dino
    train_stats = train_one_epoch(student, teacher, teacher_without_ddp, dino_loss,
  File "/home/tulsishah_google_com/dino/main_dino.py", line 330, in train_one_epoch
    loss.backward()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 492, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 251, in backward
    Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: FIND was unable to find an engine to execute this computation
[2023-12-04 13:18:07,665] torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api: [ERROR] failed (exitcode: 1) local_rank: 0 (pid: 1531298) of binary: /opt/conda/bin/python3.10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/torchrun", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/errors/__init__.py", line 346, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 806, in main
    run(args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 797, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 134, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 264, in launch_agent
    raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError:
```